Stop spring security's auto-generating password
I was trying to add authentication for my website using spring security I tried to stop auto-generating password of spring security the code has no error but the I couldn't stop password generation
@Service
public class customUserServiceImplementation implements UserDetailsService {
    
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public customUserServiceImplementation(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository=userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if(user==null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserName not found exception - "+username);
        }
        
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities=new ArrayList<>();
        
        
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),user.getPassword(),authorities);
    }
}

this is the code to stop auto-generating

Spring Security's default behavior is to generate a random password when using InMemoryUserDetailsManager or similar configurations without explicitly setting a password. This behavior is controlled by the DefaultPasswordEncoder, which generates and logs the password on startup.
To prevent Spring Security from auto-generating a password and instead set your own, one can follow below steps:
1. Define a Custom Security Configuration
Create a class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (for Spring Security 5.4 and earlier) or implements SecurityFilterChain (for Spring Security 5.5 and later). In this class, you can configure your own user details service and set specific usernames and passwords.
For Spring Security 5.4 and Earlier:
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .withUser("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}

For Spring Security 5.5 and Later:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        var user = User.withUsername("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance()::encode)
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}

2. Exclude the Default Password Logging
In application.properties, you can suppress the auto-generated password logging by setting the property spring.security.user.password to an empty value. However, the above custom configuration will override this behavior, so it's typically unnecessary when defining your own security configuration.
spring.security.user.password=

